# drupal-----add a field to the content type story

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, hook

now, i want to add a dead time field(the style is 02-12-2010) to the content type story. how to do that, i used the hook_form_alter() and format_date(),but when i created a new article,and select the time.but  the time can't show on the article's page.why?

Comment: While you are changing the node create form I don't think you are saving the entered value anywhere. A powerful and easy solution is given by H.Josef, though if your intent is to learn custom module programming you'll need to use hook_node_api and have somewhere to save your additional content.

Comment: i want to learn custom module programming ,so i like to use  hook_node_api ,could you give me an example,thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't try contributed modules instead?

A more elegant solution I think will be using the [**CCK**](http://drupal.org/project/cck) module which provides the ability of adding new fields to content types (as well as creating new content types), you can install then the **Date** module provides you with the ability to attach date fields to content types.

Comment: +1. hook_node_api would accomplish what the poster is trying to do, but CCK is far better in every way.

Comment: if i want to use hook_node_api how should i do, could you give me an example.

Comment: Here is an example of nodeapi: http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example--nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_nodeapi/6 but I have to agree that CCK + Date module is by far a better way to go, given the integration with views and other contrib modules you get for free going that route.